# How would you represent date of birth in your java model?

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

And wait, don't rush to answer "java.util.Date", consider the following scenario.

Person object having 2 fields: "birthday" and "nextMeeting" both java.util.Date.
Now birthday stored in database as date type column (no time) for eg. 01-10-1979, and nextMeeting as datetime type for ex. 01-10-2010 20:00:00.

You pull it from db, "birthday" will be auto set to midnight by JDBC.
Now you need to send this object to other JVM using lets say RMI or whatever technology.

On the other end JVM has timezone -1h from originating JVM. This is where problem starts.
nextMeeting become 01-10-2010 19:00:00 which is absolutely FINE and CORRECT from user perspective etc...

BUT birthday become 30-09-1979 23:00:00 which will be represented to user as 30th of September, which is really not what we want, cause obviously birthday is something static and NOT dependent on timezones.

So column type in db chosen correctly (date). This type of column usually represented as java.util.Date. But in our case it is wrong java type to use.

So how would you represent a birthday? Consider that you need to manipulate this object on a UI like in a datepicker component etc...

Comment: Do you mean 30th of Sept? 31st no chance ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) from [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and only store the date for the birthday, not the time.

Comment: Yeah, good to go. The only concern can be having JodaTime in both JVMs. But again that might not that big of an issue.

Comment: Looks like the way to go. I found it is possible to make hibernate understand this type, but I did not find so far is that possible to convert LocalDate back to date to use inside DatePicker components.

Comment: So will consider this as an answer, how ever this not helping me in my particular case. To simplify question I did not mention that "other end" is actually GWT client side, hence is JS, therefore not having Joda :(

Comment: If the other end is GWT - consider using plain text or goda time (http://code.google.com/p/goda-time/)

Comment: FYI, the makers of Joda-Time have said we should migrate to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework as soon as is convenient. While Joda-Time continues to be actively maintained, future work will be going into java.time and it's extension, the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

Answer (score 18):

The other answers use outmoded classes.

## java.time

Both Joda-Time and the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. Back-ported to Java 6 & 7 by the [ThreeTen-BackPort](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, which is wrapped for Android by the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

### `LocalDate`

A date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone can be represented by the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. Such a class was lacking in the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. The old `java.sql.Date` class pretends to be date-only but in fact has a time-of-day inherited from `java.util.Date` (a date-time value).

```
LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.of( 1979 , 1 , 10 );
```

Without a time of day nor time zone, a date of birth is inherently inaccurate for determining one’s age. But in nearly all use-cases we don't care; give-or-take part of a day is close enough.

### `ZonedDateTime`

For a meeting we cannot be so loosey-goosey. We need a date, a time, and a time zone. In java.time that means `ZonedDateTime` class. The **time zone is the key element** missing from the scenario in the Question. Add the time zone and all is well.

```
ZoneId zoneIdMontreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = ZonedDateTime.of( 2010 , 1 , 10 , 20 , 0 , 0 , zoneIdMontreal );
```

Now communicate the objects to another machine. Both remain intact, the same date-only value for date-of-birth (1979-01-10) and the same Montréal date-time for the meeting.

### Adjust time zone

You might then want to adjust that meeting to another time zone expected by the person using this other machine.

```
ZoneId zoneIdParis = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdtParis = zdtMontreal.withZone( zoneIdParis );
```

We have the same moment on the timeline represented in two fashions, in two objects, zdtMontreal & zdtParis.

### `LocalDateTime`

If your `nextMeeting` has no time zone nor offset-from-UTC info, then represent as a `LocalDateTime` object. In the database it would be stored as a type like `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

Such values do *not* represent a moment in the timeline. They represent only a range of possible moments. To determine an actual moment you must provide the context of a specific time zone.

For storing future date-time values such as a planned meeting further out than a few weeks, doing so without time zone may be appropriate. Politicians around the world have shown a proclivity for often changing Daylight Saving Time and otherwise redefining their time zones. And they often do so with little warning, as little as only several weeks warning.

To determine an actual moment such as showing a schedule in a calendar, apply a time zone `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

### ISO 8601

The java.time classes use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. The `ZonedDateTime` class goes one step further by extending ISO 8601 to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

If serializing values via text, use to the sensible and unambiguous formats of ISO 8601.

None of the issues raised in the Question remain. Using an excellent date-time library and ISO 8601 such as java.time solves the problem.

### Database

Your database should use date-only type for the birthdate, and a timestamp-with-time-zone type for the meeting (see [SQL data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types) in Wikipedia and in your database’s documentation). Your JDBC driver mediates both types for you.

Eventually JDBC drivers will be updated to directly use java.time types. But until then we must convert to java.sql types such as [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) and [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). New methods have been added to the old classes to support these conversions.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDateOfBirth = java.sql.Date.valueOf( dateOfBirth );
java.sql.Timestamp sqlMeeting = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf( zdtMontreal );
```

Then call `setDate` and `setTimestamp` on your `PreparedStatement`.

Going the other direction, from database to Java, call `getDate` and `getTimestamp` on your `ResultSet`. Then translate immediately to java.time types, avoiding the use of the java.sql types in your business logic.

For the date-time value, we must go through an `Instant` object. The `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). We apply a time zone to get a [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) for the user.

```
LocalDate dateOfBirth = mySqlDate.toLocalDate();
Instant instant = mySqlTimestamp.toInstant();
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneIdMontreal );
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, the two java systems will have to agree on Calendar/TimeZone information, or the Date object will need to be converted to a timestamp when being passed to the remote system.

The simplest method might be to simply require all clients to treat the birthday as a GMT time --- when they display/compare/whatever the birthdays, have them create a `Calendar` with the `"GMT"` `TimeZone`, and then `setTime()` on it with the supplied `Date`.

If you're working with the model locally at all, you should really have a Date object, not just a timestamp.

Comment: AFAIU, functionality is working like charm, its the birthday which is special, hence should be immutable. Means no change whatsoever.

Comment: Yes....? I was talking about the birthday, and making both systems agree on an interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

For manipulation i will advise java.util.Calendar

For representation

> Birthday as java.util.Date 
>   NextMeetin as java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

That's a very good question...

Android for example stores birthday as String in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format. I was wondering why they don't use java.util.Date and I guess that the reason would be the same problem which you brought here.

So I would recomment either String or some "Timezone-independent-date". But after few minutes searching in Java and joda-time documentation I have no idea how to do it.

EDIT: Seems @Jeroen is right - use LocalDate.

Answer (score -1):

if you are dealing with dates, you are better of using [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). You can build a [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html) object with date/time and timezone info so you have all info needed to deal with different timezones.

Comment: DateTime object contains time -> hence it will not work. @Jeroens answer is right.