# Which Time/Date type for what?

Tags: java, database, spring, rest, date

```
@Entity //jpa
@Data //lombok
public ExampleEntity {
 ??     entitesBirthday;       // yyyy.MM.dd
 ??     exactEntitesBirthday;  // yyyy.MM.dd-hh:mm:ss
 ??     entryCreatedAt;        // yyyy.MM.dd-hh:mm:ss,nnnnnnnnn  
}
```

As JPA Entity which one should I choose and why?

- java.util.Date
- java.sql.TimeStamp
- java.sql.Date
- java.time.Instant
- java.time.LocalDate
- java.time.LocalDateTime
- long ( a long that counts seconds from 1.1.1970)
- something else ? ( yoda ? )

there is a REST-API with path variables (e.g. localhost:8082/lookBetween/'StartDate'/'EndDate') and get requests witch json responses. Something like

```
{
    entitesBirthday: "witch format here ?"
    exactEntitesBirthday: "the ISO8601 ? "
    entryCreatedAt: "Or counted secounds ?"      
}
```

After some thinking I came up with this:

Use Instant everywhere ( because you can confirm Instant easily to LocalDate or LocalDateTime) 
For the Rest Interface I use the iso ( "20200109T213604Z" )

unlucky for me the examples provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) don't compile to Instant with the parse function.
So I have to use a formater in every ControllerClass ( Spring ) or is it ( somehow ) possible to say Spring’s JSON implementation if you have the Object Instant parse them to the ISO format and you will arrive in the rest api this String and convert the String to an Instant object ?

Or is my approach unlikely - because too complex ?

Comment: Good question. Most of it has been covered before, though you may have to piece it together from multiple questions and answers. One example is [Whats the difference between java.util.Date and Zoneddatetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911481/whats-the-difference-between-java-util-date-and-zoneddatetime) Please search for the rest.

Comment: `entitesBirthday`: `LocalDate`. `Instant` for the two others. I’d stay away from the two `Date` classes and `Timestamp`, all of which are poorly designed and long outdated. I wouldn’t use Joda-Time either, it’s been replaced by java.time. For JSON use ISO 8601 format. [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) produces that.

Comment: Does this answer the first part of your question? [How would you represent date of birth in your java model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031008/how-would-you-represent-date-of-birth-in-your-java-model)

Comment: What’s the precise requirement for `exactEntitesBirthday`? I was born at 4:30 PM. That is, it was 4:30 in the time zone where I was born. Would you want the time in my time zone or in your time zone or would you just want the moment in time in a time zone neutral way?

Comment: ```exactEntitesBirthday``` is an example for a DateTime ( precison in secs)
```entitesBirthday``` example for Date 
``` ```

Comment: Oh you are right! Only UTC Time 'counts' local information adds up the front end so the api will provide it with the UTC Time and with another call it gets the local so the frontend will add the time zone